# LCR Odds - 6 'C's in a row.

Tags: probability

Played the game LCR.  One unlucky guy rolled 3 - 'C's and then to make matters worse rolled 3 - 'C's again on his next turn.  So what are the odds of that happening?

Comment: How many Cs are on a die? How many dice did he roll each turn? How many faces/die?

Answer (score 1):

As there is one C out of six faces, the chance of rolling three of them is $(\frac 16)^3=\frac 1{216}$  The chance of doing it twice in a row is the square of this, $\frac 1{6^6}=\frac 1{46656}$  assuming the rolls are truly random

Answer (score 0):

While @Ross's answer is entirely correct, there is a broader question here.  The question asked "what are the odds of that happening".  What is "that"?  The specific event of rolling six C's in a row does indeed have probability $\frac{1}{46656}$.

However, if instead your unlucky friend had rolled six R's in a row, you would think that was equally unlikely, and you would still be here asking that same question.  The probability of rolling either six C's or six R's in a row is twice Ross's answer, or $\frac{2}{46656}=\frac{1}{23328}$.

Another unlucky situation is losing three counters (the maximum), for two turns in a row.  The  probability of that happening is $(\frac{1}{2})^6=\frac{1}{64}$, which is actually not that unlikely at all.